# Creating links from custom taxonomy categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set up a custom taxonomy for a custom post type (cpt) and have used `get_categories` to call the list of categories for the taxonomy. I've followed a few other posts to try and turn this list into category links but I seem to have come unstuck. Can anyone help? This is where I'm at so far:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach(get_categories("taxonomy=trade&orderby=name&orderby=count&order=DESC&hide_empty=0") as $category) {echo '
<li class="cat-item cat-item-'.$category->cat_ID.'">
<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'" title="'.$category->category_description.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>
</li>';} ?>
</ul>
```

The issue I'm having is that the above generates links but they're empty

```
<a href="" title="">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: How stupid of me!! I've edited the post to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing yourself here, and me too :-). Don't use `get_categories()` for custom taxonomies, use `get_terms`. Yes, `get_categories()` works, but creates confusion as you tend to carry on with category function as you did.

`get_category_link()` only work with terms connected to the build in taxonomy `category`, it does not work with custom taxonomy terms. You should be using [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) for custom taxonomies